# jQuery to set star rating Dymanic

Tags: jquery, html

I want set star rating dynamic from database, i used below code and success to set value, but i not to set readonly status

jQuery on document ready

```
$('.raty').raty({
    readOnly: function () {
        return $(this).attr('data-read');
    },
    score: function () {
        return $(this).attr('data-rating');
    }
});
```

Html script 1st and 2nd row sample

```
<div class="raty" data-rating="3" data-read='false'>
<div class="raty" data-rating="4" data-read='true'>
```

Comment: This is very unclear.  What exactly is you're question?

Comment: i want to set star rating and readonly false/true dynamic , value set properly but readonly status always true for every row even i set false value

Comment: @Raj Make sure code is in [DOM ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) and better use `$(this).data('rating');`

Comment: @Tushar actually i am retrieving some data from database on page load event and set rating to each row, code is not DOM Ready

Comment: @Raj are you using $.ajax ??

Comment: @Tuhar no ,just in aspx page i am adding row like [ <tr><td>row data from databse</td></tr> ]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.raty').raty({
    readOnly: true,
    score: function () {
        return $(this).attr('data-rating');
    }
});
```

**Updated answer**:

**html:**

```
<div class="raty" data-rating="3" data-read='false'>
<div class="raty" data-rating="4" data-read='false'>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(".raty").each(function() {
  $(this).raty({
    readOnly: true,
    score: function () {
        return $(this).attr('data-rating');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but above code will set readonly to all rows, i want to set readonly false to some rows. then???????

Comment: @Joke_Senses10 i will have to add jquery for every id which is not proper way to solve my problem , and my code is not DOM Ready so Dynamically added jquery for each id will not work

Comment: This should solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933121/how-to-control-target-in-a-multiple-jquery-raty-system

Comment: in that code readonly value set by default in jquery , which i want to set from html side for each row Like : 
<div class="raty" data-rating="3" readonly='false'>
<div class="raty" data-rating="4" readonly='true'>

Comment: you have set readyonly=true; in jquery. but what should i change if i want to set readyonly=false; to some rows dynamically ???????

Comment: Finnaly I solve this problem , i write two function like : 

> $('.raty_w').raty({    readOnly : false,
>              score: function(){
>                       return $(this).attr('data-rating');
>                      }  });
> 
>  $('.raty_r').raty({    readOnly : true,
>              score: function(){
>                       return $(this).attr('data-rating');
>                      }  });

set separate class name 1st'raty_r' for readyonly:false;
 2nd'raty_w' for readyonly:true;
<div class="raty_r" data-rating='3' ></div>
    <div class="raty_w" data-rating='4' ></div>